# Express route with params followed by route without params

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 routes on the following structure:

router.get('/person/:id')

router.get('/person/friends')

The request: **GET /person/1** is being handled by the first route by the order that I wrote them.

this order:

router.get('/person/:id')

router.get('/person/friends')

will go to **'/person/:id**

while this one:

router.get('/person/friends')

router.get('/person/:id')

will go to **'/person/friends'**

Am I using the format for params wrong? isn't **:id** means that it expects a variable, while /friends expect the same string "friends" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression for this purpose, to filter paths, e.g.

```
app.get("^/person/:id([0-9]{1,6})", function(req, res, next){
    console.log('/person/:id endpoint hit: id: ' + req.params.id);
    res.end('OK');
});

app.get("/person/friends", function(req, res, next){
    console.log('/person/friends endpoint hit');
    res.end('OK');
});
```

This will mean that any requests like: http://localhost:3000/person/42 will go to the :/id handler and requests like http://localhost:3000/person/friends will go to the /friends handler. You can change the regex as you like, I've assumed a 1 to 6-digit number for the ID.

You could make this more permissive to allow any amount of digits by doing something like:

```
app.get("^/person/:id([0-9]+)", function(req, res, next){
    console.log('/person/:id endpoint hit: id: ' + req.params.id);
    res.end('OK');
});
```

If you don't specify a regex pattern, the request /person/friends will match the /person/:id handler and you'll get this in your logs:

```
/person/:id endpoint hit: id: friends
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I wonder if isn't it a bug of express though. Shouldn't ":id" be treated different than a string that isn't a param?

Comment: Well it's a route parameter so a string is perfectly legitimate. You could use a string in which case you'd change the regex.